# \pdfgentounicode=1 throwing 'undefined control sequence' error

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I have been trying to make my cv pass through cv-parsers. I read and found out that I have to use the **\input glyphtounicode** and the **\pdfgentounicode=1** commands. I added the **glyphtounicode.tex** file in Overleaf and the aforementioned commands and compiled. It threw me a **undefined control sequence** error. I don't know to which part of my latex code I should add these statements. Could someone please guide me? Here's how my code looks.

```
\documentclass[]{resume-openfont}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\resetHeaderAndFooter

\newcommand{....}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\begin{document}
      \pdfgentounicode=1
...rest of the body
\end{document}
```

Comment: make a small, real example without some dots, and then show the log-file.

Comment: What engine are you using?